# Fill a user and password fields on a browser, from software on a mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I know its a general question, but we have to get some direction to check if we can do that or not ,and we are developers for the iOS so mac is a little bit different .

Is that possible,to have a software for a mac ,that runs in the background ,and at some point, that software send data to your browser-that fills automatically the fields on the screen such as user name and passwords , or other fields ? (it has to "find" the relevant fields and fill them) .

Or is that software should be on a browser instead ?  is that legal ?
Are there companies who do that in some way ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

An app called [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) does this, although it is driven by user action. 1Password can store website logins, among other things, and a user can have 1Password fill in the username and password fields and submit the web form to complete the login.

Answer (score 0):

That would be considered high sequrity risk, you wouldn't be able to do that without "hacking". The Web browser must be open and the software might use the FindWindow command or something like that but you wouldn't be able to do that without being called "hacker"